# Sum of unique integers in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, integer

Question : You are given an integer array nums. The unique elements of an array are the elements that appear exactly once in the array.

Return the sum of all the unique elements of nums.

I started of the code with trying to remove all non unique numbers and adding the unique numbers to a separate list. However when i print the new list it returns the exact same list as the original (on leetcode). Could anyone help me in fixing this problem? Thanks!

```
class Solution:
def sumOfUnique(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    lists = []
    double = []
    for i in nums:
        if nums not in lists:
            lists.append(i)
        if nums in lists:
            lists.remove(i)
        else:
            pass
    print(lists)
```

Comment: You're checking whether the entire input list, `nums`, is in `lists`. You meant to check whether `i` is in `lists`. And there's no need to remove things afterward, nor an `else: pass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues in the current implementation as it stands:

1. You use multiple `if` block implying they are independent of each other so it will remove the element from the list every time it is added. I would suggest to use a `dict` object instead as imagine the element occurs odd number of times (say, 3) then you would add, remove and re-add the element.
2. `if nums not in lists` is not correct, probably you meant `if i not in lists`.

Here is simplified version of the method without the class:

```
def sumOfUnique(nums):
    counts = {}
    for i in nums:
        if i in counts.keys():
            counts[i] += 1
        else:
            counts[i] = 1

    uniques = [k for k, v in counts.items() if v == 1]
    print(uniques)
    return sum(uniques)  # return the sum of the list elements

print(sumOfUnique([1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any constraint on the data structures you can use, it should be as simple as

```py
def sumOfUnique(your_input_list):
    result = sum(set(your_input_list))
    return result
```

**Set** gives you an unordered collection of unique items.

Comment: They only want to sum over the numbers that appear exactly once in the list. This will sum over all the distinct numbers independent how often they appear in the list.

Comment: @Saverio Guzzo , the function set() returns a list of unique integers , where i need a set of unique integers , where if there are more than one of an integer we remove it from the final sum

Answer (score 2):

To sum over the numbers that appear exactly once in your list you could do something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

my_dct = Counter(my_list)
total = sum(k for k, v in my_dct.items() if v == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here with your if statements is that you first test if nums is not in lists, in case you add it to the list, and then you test again if nums is in the list (without using elif or an else condition), and this is always going to be True. And also you're testing if nums is in your list and not the i variable which what you're iterating with in your for loop. So maybe take some time to find the right conditions before you try to translate it into code.

Answer (score 0):

Updated: use Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

class Solution:
    
    def sumOfUnique(self, nums):
        counts = Counter(nums)
        unique_list = [x for x in counts if counts[x] == 1]
        return sum(unique_list)
```

Comment: That returns a list of [1, 2, 3], but i want a l list of [1, 3] to be returned as the number two is not unique in this list

Comment: @D-python I've updated the answer using Counter instead of set.